# Password reset for IIS application pool identity

Tags: iis, application-pool, change-password

I have a domain account that is configured as the identity for the app pool in IIS that runs my web service. I need to change the LAN password for the account.

Can I change the LAN password first, then set the new password in IIS (manually, quickly within the same minute) so that my web service keeps running uninterrupted, or it starts failing immediately before I have the chance to update the password?

My web service is heavily used 24x7. Also the website is connecting to back-end resources (e.g. database) using the same domain account. So I can imagine the account might remain authenticated on the IIS server for a while, but a call to database needs re-authentication and fails before I update the password in IIS. However it is complicated to test it, hence asking here.

Ultimately I would like to figure out if the password change can be carried out without disruption, or I must declare an outage - which is a hassle. The worst I would like to avoid is that I change the pwd and the service starts failing.

Comment: For normal domain accounts, you won't have any other way to sync password changes but to manually update the stored passwords in IIS configuration. That's exactly why since Windows Server 2016 Group Managed Service Accounts were introduced to AD, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/getting-started-with-group-managed-service-accounts?source=recommendations Work with your domain administrators and they can configure that for you.